# What is the pattern to copy only json files using Azure CopyFiles@2?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am using Azure CopyFiles@2 in pipeline.yaml file to copy json file from root folder to drop location, but it's copying everything.

I have tried below code.

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: "Copy Files to: $(DropLocation)"
  condition: always()
  inputs:
      SourceFolder: $(build.sourcesdirectory)
      Contents: "**/*.json"
      TargetFolder: "$(DropLocation)"
      flattenFolders: true
```

Please let me know the correct pattern to copy only json files which are at $(build.sourcesdirectory) location.

Comment: Your task setting will copy all *.json files including the ones in subfolders, it won't copy everything. If you are checking the `$(DropLocation)` content, make sure it's empty before the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only want the root folder, you shouldn't specify "**/", which will copy every Json file in the subfolders.

Change the Contents to simply:

```yaml
Contents: "*.json"
```

*Additional note: You can also remove `flattenFolders: true` since that would apply only if you wanted to copy the files in subfolders.*

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the option "Flatten Folders" is actually forcing a copy of all contents, as per documentation at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/copy-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml

I quote:

> flattenFolders - Flatten Folders
>
> boolean. Default value: false.
>
> Optional. Flattens the folder structure and copies all files into the specified target folder.

So removing that option should fix this.
In your search pattern you're specifying all sub-directories, too with the ** syntax, so there's no need to flatten.

Comment: By copying all files, it's meant the files already filtered by `Contents`.

Comment: If true, that's really unfortunate and the documentation is not clear at all. Even changing this to "All specified files" or "All files matching the defined pattern" would help.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a sample code to achieve the following functions (**copy file** -> **publish to drop**, just copy and run.)

```
variables:
- name: DropLocation
  value: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'create a json file'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      New-Item -Path $(Build.SourcesDirectory) -Name "testfile1.json" -ItemType "file" -Value "{This is a text string.}"

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(DropLocation)'
  condition: always()
  inputs:
      SourceFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
      Contents: testfile1.json
      TargetFolder: $(DropLocation)
      flattenFolders: false

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: Publish the result to drop
  inputs:
    targetPath: $(DropLocation)/testfile1.json
    artifactName: drop
```

1. simulated a file in `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` (for windows agent actual is: `D:\a\1\s`)
2. copy the simulated file from `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` (windows agent is: `D:\a\1\a`)
3. publish the `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\testfile.json` to drop